# How to insert return value from last EXECUTE PROCEDURE in INFORMIX

Tags: stored-procedures, return-value, informix

This should be relatively easy but I'm new with informix.

I have a stored proc that I am calling with `EXECUTE PROCEDURE`. The proc is roughly as follows (but with a ton more columns):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MYPROC (
    foo int,
    bar int
) returning int;
```

How can I use that `int` *from the Informix prompt* to use it in a subsequent insert?

This is roughly what I would like to do. I do not have the option to change the insides of the proc.

```
> EXECUTE PROCEDURE MYPROC(foo,bar);

(expression)

        4104

1 row(s) retrieved.

> INSERT INTO MYTABLE(val) VALUES(I_DONT_KNOW_WHAT_GOES_HERE);
```

I have already tried this

```
> INSERT INTO MYTABLE(val) VALUES(
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE MYPROC(foo,bar)
);
```

and failed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the output of a `FUNCTION` or `PROCEDURE` in most places where an expression is expected. So this should be all you need:

```
> INSERT INTO MYTABLE(val) VALUES( MYPROC(foo,bar) );
```

---

**Update**

Further discussion in comments has identified that the procedure has some DML in it, so the solution above does not work. (Informix does not permit this, presumably to avoid endless looping and recursion).

You might have more luck with this (untested):

```
INSERT INTO mytable 
SELECT a.result FROM TABLE(myproc('foo','bar')) AS a(result)
```

But it might also be refused for the same reason as the original.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it, actually I'm doing an update: `UPDATE someTable set id= MYPROC(foo,bar) WHERE ...;` and it gives me `675: Illegal SQL statement in SPL routine.`

Comment: That suggests that the function is itself performing some DML? That might not be permitted.

Comment: The function does indeed make some inserts.

Comment: That would explain it. You'll need to go about it differently.

Comment: Thanks. what I ended up doing was that I used a custom-made sub-select to get the same result number again, after executing the proc, and then I inserted that number into my table. If someone has a better solution I'd still be interested to know.

Comment: If you were using some embedded language like ESQL/C or Perl DBI, it's trivial to store the result of the SPL in a variable and then save that with an INSERT in a procedural fashion.